# How is Vue App deployed after build correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-cli

I deployed a Vue App on an hosting platform, i got to know that if i serve

`"www.mydomain.com/about"` and hit enter, i get 404 Error Page. have i deployed the wrong thing?

`npm run build`

**note: the dist folder was deployed after build**

[Text](https://al-maruf-oluyole.com/about)

but when you remove `/about`, the real page got served, and also when you click on the links on the navbar, it shows the about pages. but when you refresh the pages, it return 404 Error.

Why is this so?

Comment: Huh, that's some interesting behavior. Can you provide a copy of your router config file? I expect lazy loading might be the culprit

Comment: Actually, I found your router config. Try this. For one page, we'll go with the About page. Import that component into your router, then in the route object, change the component from `() => import("../views/About")` to point directly to that component. Redeploy and see if browsing directly to About works then.

Comment: further detail here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations, this goes into 404s when routing directly. This means the issue might be more related to history mode routing than it is to lazy loading

Comment: like @Tanner said its probably the history mode. you can check it easily but go to www.mydomain.com/#about and if its works its 100% history mode problem

Comment: @Tanner, what you suggested didn't work, still the same... Thank you. any other suggestions is welcome.

Comment: @AbdulAzeezOlanrewaju - I believe Ignacio's answer is going to be the most likely cause - were you able to look at the link provided?

Comment: Yes, i tried putting things in the vue.config.js, still the same

Answer (score 2):

You need to config your server because, you are resolving the routes with the server, and not with vue (When you click on the navbar and go to /about, you can access, because you are resolving the route with vue).

[Check this link](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Comment: your suggestion will surely work, how do i write it in my vue.config file

Comment: Another problem is that when i hosted it on firebase, it worked normally, no problem... but that platform which i hosted it, it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Uou are using Vue router's history mode. For any page URL to work for vue in this case you will have to make some changes in your web server's configuration. Here are 2 of the most common config settings. Make these changes, restart your web server and your issue will be resolved.

Apache

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

nginx

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Full documentation available at https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html.